# Using python to select only the non ascii characters in a string

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

If i have a string called mystring and it has stored in it: *Ümeå* I would like to store the non ascii characters *Üå* in a list.

Below is my code, and it is almost working, but the list contains hex characters (ie \xc3\xa6) rather than the correctly encoded chars :

```
try:
   mystring.iloc[i].decode('ascii')
   i+=1
except:
   nonascii_string = str(mystring.iloc[i])
   j=0
   #now we've found the string, isolate the non ascii characters
   for item in str(profile_data_nonascii_string):
      try:
         str(nonascii_string[j].decode('ascii'))
         j+=1
      except:
         # PROBLEM: Need to work out how to encode back to proper UTF8 values
         nonascii_chars_list.append(str(nonascii_string[j]))
         j+=1
      i+=1
      pass
```

I think i need to do something like:

```
chr(profile_data_nonascii_string[j].encode('utf-8'))
```

but of course doing that only selects the first byte of my multibyte character (and hence throws an error). I am sure there is a simple solution... :-|

Comment: Please reduce your code to a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Copy-paste that program in its entirety into your question. See [ask] and [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Use [`codec.decode(string, errors='ignore')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes)

Comment: Also, what type is `mystring`? `iloc` is not a method on the built-in `str` type in either Python2 or Python3.

Comment: My apologies. Wasn't a good question because of the incomplete info.. In trying to make it simpler, I removed some of the info (ie such that I was using Pandas)... Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping if the chars you want to remove and `str.translate` them from the string:

```
In [29]: tbl = dict.fromkeys(range(128), u"")

In [30]: s = u'Ümeå'

In [31]: print(s.translate(tbl))
Üå
```

In pandas which you seem to be using you can use [pandas.Series.str.translate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.translate.html).

**Series.str.translate(table, deletechars=None)**

> Map all characters in the string through the given mapping table. Equivalent to standard str.translate(). Note that the optional argument deletechars is only valid if you are using python 2. For python 3, character deletion should be specified via the table argument.

`translate` is going to be more efficient than `str.join`:

```
In [7]: s = 'Ümeå' * 1000

In [8]: timeit ''.join([x for x in s if ord(x) > 127])
1000 loops, best of 3: 489 µs per loop

In [9]: timeit s.translate(tbl)
1000 loops, best of 3: 289 µs per loop
In [10]: s.translate(tbl) ==  ''.join([x for x in s if ord(x) > 127])
Out[10]: True
```

For pandas with python2, you need `deletechars` with None:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: raw_data = {'Name' : pd.Series(['david','åndrëw','calvin'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name'])

In [5]: delete = "".join(map(chr,range(128)))

In [6]: print df['Name'].str.translate(None, delete)
a      
b    åë
c      
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

For python3 using the dict works fine:

```
In [9]: import pandas as pd

In [10]: raw_data = {'Name' : pd.Series(['david','åndrëw','calvin'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

In [11]: 

In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name'])

In [12]: 

In [12]: delete = dict.fromkeys(range(128), "")

In [13]: df['Name'].str.translate(delete)
Out[13]: 
a      
b    åë
c      
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

The different approaches needed are documented:

**Parameters:**

> table : dict (python 3), str or None (python 2)
>   In python 3, table is a mapping of Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, strings, or None. Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None are deleted. str.maketrans() is a helper function for making translation tables. In python 2, table is either a string of length 256 or None. If the table argument is None, no translation is applied and the operation simply removes the characters in deletechars. string.maketrans() is a helper function for making translation tables.
>   deletechars : str, optional (python 2)
>   A string of characters to delete. This argument is only valid in python 2.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am trying to use the series.str.translate, but getting the error "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas"... Any reason why? I can't seem to get this working in ipython notebook either, it seems to convert my series into a float type and report all values as NaN (although your str.translate works).... Appreciate the help

Comment: If you add a snippet of the df and the outcome you want it will help

Comment: **import pandas as pd**  
\n
 **raw_data = {'Name' : pd.Series(['david','åndrëw','calvin'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}**
\n    
**df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name'])**
\n       
**tbl = dict.fromkeys(range(128), u"")**
\n
I then try: **df['Name'].str.translate(tbl)**

But returns NaN values... Not sure what I am doing wrong..

Comment: @Calamari, there is a difference between 2 and 3 as stated in the docs,  I edited the answer with a working solution for python2

Comment: Thanks for this. Missed the difference between 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I separated the non-ASCII chars from the string your example string:

```
In [7]: s=u'Ümeå'

In [8]: print s
Ümeå

In [9]: s2 = u''.join(x for x in s if ord(x) > 126)

In [10]: print s2
Üå
```

Or, if you prefer your answers in a list:

```
In [15]: s=u'Ümeå'

In [16]: print s
Ümeå

In [17]: s2 = list(x for x in s if ord(x) > 126)

In [18]: print s2[0]
Ü

In [19]: print s2[1]
å
```

Comment: ASCII has 128 characters, so you want `ord(x) > 127`.

Comment: ASCII 127 is DEL. I assumed that the OP really meant "printable ASCII", so I want `ord(x) > 126`. Regardless, OP should take your comment into account if he adapts my code.

Comment: In that case, you'd need `not (31 < ord(x) < 127)` (i.e. exclude all of the ASCII control characters, not just DEL).